# Cordova 3.4.0 : File Api GetFile Abort Error

Tags: javascript, ios, file, cordova

Recently upgraded Cordova framework of my app to 3.4.0

I used to write a file within the Documents directory of iOS app. 
the file access code snippet is as shown below.

```
var path = "/var/mobile/Applications/MyApp/Documents/tempDir/txtFile.txt";
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
            function(fileSystem){

                fileSystem.root.getFile(path,{create:true, exclusive: false},
                        function(fileEntry){
                            console.log('gotFileEntry');

                                );
                        },
                        function(){
                            console.log('gotFileEntry fail');
                            }
                        );

            }, 
            function(){
                console.log('fail');
                }
            );
```

In the newer version of cordova(3.4.0) it is failing to get the fileentry and throwing an error code = 3 i.e ABORT_ERR

Please help me on this. As my complete module depends on this.
Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: I am taking a guess that the current version does not allow you to access arbitrary paths. You need to just specify the file name. Try by just specifying the filename "txtFile.txt" instead of the whole path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after digging Cordova FILE plugin, found out that the file path passed should be relative in the latest version. refer [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md)